# Are deictic pronouns at all apparent in written language?

Tags: pragmatics, pronouns

Considering the nature of deixis, I have trouble coming up with written examples where the pronoun is of a deictic nature, other than quotes from speech etc. Or maybe I have misunderstood the meaning of a deictic pronoun?

Comment: Check if this is how you understand the concept of deictic pronouns: they refer to entities that must be identified according to the context. For instance: in the sentence `I will give you an answer about deictic pronouns`, the deictic pronouns `I` and `you` refer to the speaker and the addressee, respectively. I'm not sure what you mean by "written examples" though, so maybe this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I never even thought about that dialogue can occur in written text, so obviously deictic pronouns exist outside speech! My original thought was more about formally written language: articles, non-fiction, etc.

Comment: I would say the line between deixis and anaphora is blurred. That is why the same pronoun can often be used both deictically and anaphorically!

Comment: I will edit my first comment as an answer and reply to @Cerberus too.

Answer (score 2):

In spite of their differences, written and oral language don't differ too much in deixis, I think. Deixis is not only concerned with quotes. It refers to the extralinguistic world: yesterday, tomorrow, he, she...These are different categories (adverbs, pronouns...) but they have this propriety in common. Anafora and Catafora refer to precedent and previous speech, respectively, thus, a link to deixis can be seen.
Sorry for the mistakes, it's difficult to explain such a thing in English (I'm Spaniard) but I hope to have shed some light in this issue.
Best regards.
María José Barrios (Spain)

Comment: When you say that there is a link to deixis with cataphoric and anaphoric uses, you are not clear enough about the difference between such uses and deictic uses of pronouns. I tried to explain the difference in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Deictic** pronouns refer to entities that must be identified according to the context of utterance. For instance, in the sentence `I will give you an answer about deictic pronouns`, the deictic pronouns `I` and `you` refer to the speaker and the addressee, respectively. Of course, there could be different referents in each context of utterance. **Anaphoric** pronouns are different. They refer back to constituents in the sentence domain. That is the case of `her` in `Mary is my wife and I love her`. In principle, pronouns cannot be both anaphoric and deictic, since they simply pick up different referents.

Comment: *They refer back to constituents in the sentence domain.* — What do you mean exactly? Anaphoric pronouns do not necessarily have to refer to constituents, I would say. Which is what I hope to show you by means of this last sentence. As I see it, anaphora means referring to something within the text, whereas deixis is referring to something outside the text, something "in the real world". And that is a distinction that is not always easy to make, if only because many things can be both in the text and in the world.

Comment: @Cerberus Your distinction between referents inside and outside the text is what I meant. However, I don't really see why it is a distinction difficult to make. If a pronoun refers to the speaker/addressee, it is deictic. If it refers back to a linguistic constituent in the sentence, it is anaphoric. If I say `I thought about myself`, I would say that `I` is deictic and `myself` is anaphoric. Can you give an example of a difficult case?